# Queries regarding C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to C++, was reading some online C++ code and have this question:

When do we overload `<` operator and when we overload `()` operator, when we are dealing with user defined Objects, Set and Map?

Analogy with Java and simple examples will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is on-topic. There's even a section of the standard devoted to it, §17.6.3.1 [utility.arg.requirements].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When to overload the `<` operator**

Say you have:

```
struct foo
{
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

There are many containers, such as `std::set` and `std::map` in the standard C++ library that work only when there is a way to sort objects.

If you want to create a set of `foo` objects, you have to let the compiler know what function can be called to compare too `foo` objects so that they can be sorted at run time. One way you allow `foo` objects to be sorted is by providing an `operator<` function.

```
struct foo
{
   int a;
   int b;
   bool operator<(const foo& rhs) const;
   {
      // Add your logic to compare too objects and return true
      // if the LHS is deemed to be less than the RHS.
   }
};
```

With that done, you can construct a set of `foo` objects:

```
std::set<foo> setOfFoo;
```

**When to overload the `()` operator**

Many functions in the standard C++ library work with fuctors. A functor is either function pointer or an instance of a struct/class that has a `()` operator.

As an example, one of the versions of the standard library function `std::sort` is defined as:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

```
    comp
        Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments,
        and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
        whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before
        the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.

        The function shall not modify any of its arguments.

        This can either be a function pointer or a function object.
```

If you want to sort a list of `foo` objects in a `std::vector`, you will have to do something like:

```
struct FooCompare
{
   bool operator()(foo const& lhs, foo const& rhs)
   {
      return (lhs < rhs);
   }
}

std::vector<foo> fooList;
// Add items to fooList

// Sort fooList
std::sort(fooList.begin(), fooList.end(), FooCompare());
```

Mind you, this is just for illustration of the `()` operator function. In real life, you should be able the use the `std::less` class for this purpose.

```
// Sort fooList
std::sort(fooList.begin(), fooList.end(), std::less<foo>());
```

Comment: To link this to the ISO standard spec, you overload `operator()` to meet the requirements for a `Callable` object, and `operator<` for `LessThanComparable`.